# Sudoers Command

Tags: command-line, unix, privileges, sudoers

I can't understand the difference in this two command's

`USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
AND
`USER ALL=(OTHERUSER) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Can anyone explain the () change?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`man 5 sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html):

> The basic structure of a user specification is `who where = (as_whom) what`.

And

> The reserved word `ALL` is a built-in alias that always causes a match to succeed.

In your case the difference is in `(as_whom)` field:

- `(ALL)` means it's possible for `USER` to run commands as any user.
- `(OTHERUSER)` means it's possible for `USER` to run commands as `OTHERUSER` (e.g. `sudo -u OTHERUSER whoami`).

  Note it doesn't mean `USER` cannot run commands as `YETANOTHERUSER`. If `USER` tries to run something as `YETANOTHERUSER` then the line with `(OTHERUSER)` won't match and the parser will continue; some later line may match.

Comment: So the `USER` can execute sudo commands as `OTHERUSER` name or will have only the privileges of the `OTHERUSER`?.

Comment: @PedroMacedoVilas The user chooses whom to impersonate explicitly with `sudo -u chosen_user some_command`, like in the example I added to my answer. If the user is allowed to run `some_command` as `chosen_user` then the command will run with privileges of `chosen_user`.